# Positioning an image to the bottom of a bootstrap thumbnail

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, position

I want to have a set of responsive thumbnails using bootstrap and I found some trouble when one of the thumbnails in X width has a caption text of one line and the other caption texts have 2 lines, so I get a difference in heights. I've solved this using some jQuery I found on stack, but now the problem is that I want to images to position to the bottom of the thumbnail so if there are other thumbnails with 2 line captions, this thumbnail with oneline caption will look like `Caption>whitespace>image`

Here's a fiddle that doesn't work like my page does but I guess it serves as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/gS864/2/

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <caption><strong>Aire Acondicionado</strong></caption>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="img-responsive" alt="Servicios">
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <caption><strong>Agua Caliente</strong></caption>
            <span id="sex"></span>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="Servicios">
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <caption><strong>Estacionamiento Privado</strong></caption>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="Servicios">
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Also you can visit the page i'm working on so you can see it directly: http://palaceh.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with modern browsers (ie11+), you could use [`css flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes/) rules.

```
.thumbnail {
    display:-webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.thumbnail .caption {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}
```

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gS864/4/